# Definition of large expression - makes PC freezed

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, built-in-symbols, system, function-comparison

```
In[1] A=Range[10^4];?A

Out[1] (* definition of  A*)
```

[image]

It works for 10^4. But if I increase the number to 10^6

```
In[1] A=Range[10^6];?A (* Do not try this *)
```

makes my PC freezed. It is even impossible to abort. The only way out is quitting mathematica without saving documents.

While I was writing this article, I recalled the command `Definition`.
`Definition[A]` doesn't make such problem.

[image]

Then my question was changed. What is advantage/disadvantage of `?` and `Definition`?

Comment: It takes about 4 minutes to show up on my machine for 10^6. Win7-Mma12.2. After that pressing Home and End keys is also sluggish. I have deleted my prev. comment that said that it hangs my computer. I decided to wait longer just to see. I think "? " should be used for function definitions, but there could be more options to discover.

Comment: ? writes out the entire list. Definition[] shows the `Short` version of the range and it takes roughly a minute on my machine.

Comment: The problem is the FrontEnd (notebook interface) trying to format long expression. Unfortunately the problem has a long history (try `Do[Print[i],{i,10000}]`  or `TracePrint` something not trivial).

I personally experimented with substituting `$Output` stream with something limiting the amount of the output.

WRI seem to be surely aware of the problem and is moving towards  multithreaded FE (which will at least give you a chance to abort) but we're not there yet.